# System.Array does not contain a definition for 'Split'

Tags: c#, system.array

I'm trying to take a string and split it. However, whenever I use `fullName.Split` Visual Studio says System.Array does not contain a definition for Split.

This is my main method so far.

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inValue;
        int noNames;
        string[] names = new string[100];
       // find number of names
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of names: ");
        inValue = Console.ReadLine();
        int.TryParse(inValue, out noNames);
        string[] fullName = new string[noNames];
        for (int i = 0; i < fullName.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] name = fullName.Split(' '); //error appears here
        }
    }
```

What's strange is that I was able to write another program shortly before this that uses the Split method. That program had no issues. I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my code, or an error with Visual Studio. Can anyone assist me in solving this error? The program isn't complete, if that matters.

Comment: What version of the .NET framework do you use?

Comment: I'm using 4.0, prior research indicated that I may not be using the right .net framework. Thankfully I have that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call it on the element of the array, not the array itself..  So it would be:

`string[] name = fullName[i].Split(' ');`

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to split an array, not a string. Arrays cannot be split this way using a certain character like strings

Comment: Thank you very much for the guidance! I did not expect this quick of a response. Everyone who takes time to answer these questions is awesome.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inValue;
        int noNames;
        string[] names = new string[100];
       // find number of names
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of names: ");
        inValue = Console.ReadLine();
        int.TryParse(inValue, out noNames);
        string[] fullName = new string[noNames];
        for (int i = 0; i < fullName.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] name = fullName[i].Split(' '); //error appears here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep, I was just missing the value. Thanks so much for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: @user1729696 If this answered your question please mark it as such